# Why does this MySQL statement cause a syntax error error?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem and could not find an answer to it. The following statement

```
SELECT (title, content, keywords, descr, sidebar) FROM staticpages WHERE  req = 'index'
```

throws the following error

```
Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '0' at line 1
```

I insert the string 'index' with mysql_real_escape_string, but I have verified that it contains 'index'. There IS an entry in the database that fits the WHERE (and even if there was not, there should not be a syntax error).

//EDIT: The query is produced by the following PHP code:

```
if ($res = $db->query("SELECT title, content, keywords, descr, sidebar FROM staticpages WHERE  req = '"+$db->real_escape_string($page)+"'")) {
    //...
} else {
    echo "Error " . $db->errno . ": " . $db->error;
}
```

`$db` contains a mysqli instance, `$page` contains the string `"index"`.

Comment: I dont think the query that you posted is full,the error message refers to a 0 that doesnt exits in your query.

Comment: @Mihai that cofuses me too. I will update the question and show you the PHP code that produces the query.

Comment: Not sure but + is the concatenate operator in javascript,in PHP is the dot. '".$db->real_escape_string($page)."'

Comment: @Mihai Uh... You are right... sorry...

Comment: *That* error message does not relate to *this* query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just my own stupidity:

In PHP, the `+` operator does NOT concatinate strings. Sorry to bother you with this question.

Solution: Use the string concatination operator `.`.

Answer (score 2):

You have two SELECT keywords

```
  SELECT SELECT (title, content, keywords, descr, sidebar) FROM staticpages WHERE  req = 'index'
  -------^
```

Remove one of those.

Comment: No, that was a typo in the question, but thank you.

Comment: @fNek, Try removing the parenthesis and give a shot.

Answer (score 0):

you have TWO selects, and field list should not be in parens...

```
select
      field1,
      field2,
      field3
   from
      yourtable
   where
      someCondition
   order by
      someFieldChosen
```

Comment: The two selects were a typo. It also does not work without parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Try this - without round brackets:

```
SELECT title, content, keywords, descr, sidebar
FROM staticpages 
WHERE  req = 'index'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `title`, `content`, `keywords`, `descr`, `sidebar` FROM staticpages WHERE  `req` = 'index'
```

Dont know what php template are you using but try

```
'".$db->real_escape_string($page)."'
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT `title`, `content`, `keywords`, `descr`, `sidebar` FROM staticpages WHERE  `req` = '[index](http://www.elso9.com)'